# Conflict between bootstrap and mathquill

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mathquill

I'm trying to use mathquill (0.10.1) to display some static latex `\sqrt{36}` and the square root sign is just a squiggle. I'm using bootstrap (4.0.0-beta.3) and when I place `<span class="mq">\sqrt{36}</span>` inside some `div`s of "class container" it exhibits this behaviour. If I put the `span` outside of these container `div`s then the presentation works fine.

I've searched for a solution and this seems to be an issue for others but the advice is to change the mathquill-rendered-math class in mathquill.css but this doesn't exist in the version I am using. Any ideas how to fix this?

P.S. I realise there are other ways of presenting mathematical notation but I want to use mathquill's on-the-fly maths notation input at some point too

Comment: In putting together a stripped down version of the page I've realised that the problem occurs when putting the latex in a collapsed card-block. Must be something to do with when the latex is being rendered. https://www.fliptmaths.co.uk/test.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I had to assign the `StaticMath` to a variable in javascript (`temp = mq.StaticMath($("#mq3")[0]`) where `mq3` was the id of the `span` with the latex inside) then use `temp.reflow()` once that area of the page was visible. As the docs say, `mathquill` uses computed dimensions so that was the problem as the latex had no dimensions when `mathquill` did its work.